# Flutter: detect if user logged with Facebook or Google

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-signin, flutter-facebook-login

User can log out doing this:

```
await _auth.signOut();
```

Because I want to ask always for an user, I also need to run also one of these lines:

```
await _googleSignIn.disconnect();
await _facebookSignIn.logOut();
```

How can I detect if the user logged in with Facebook or Google?

Answer (score 2):

`_auth.currentUser().providerData[0].providerId` does provide "google.com" or "facebook.com"